# Error: ! Can't subset `.data` outside of a data mask context

Tags: r, ggtree

this is my code:

```
p <- ggtree(tree, mrsd="2022-11-26", as.Date=TRUE,color='black',size=0.3) %<+% metadata_df + theme_tree2()
```

When I run this, it returns this error:

```
Error:
! Can't subset `.data` outside of a data mask context.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

why?

I expected it to return a tree inside the p variable.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What version of the package are you using?